# Django on_delete for Model with custom delete function

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Concert(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  is_deleted = models.BoolField(default=False)
  def delete(self):
    self.is_deleted = True
    self.save()

class Ticket(models.Model):
  concert = models.ForeignKey(Concert, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  is_deleted = models.BoolField(default=False)
  def delete(self):
    self.is_deleted = True
    self.save()
```

I noticed when I call delete on Concert, it doesn't call delete on Ticket. This is expected behavior, right? Is there any way to trigger CASCADE even in the case of this custom delete function?

Comment: Yes, it performs deletes in bulk, so the "soft delete" will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the cascade behavior is not automatically triggered when using a custom delete function.

I would probably get all the tickets related to that concert and delete them "manually"

```
def delete(self):
    self.is_deleted = True
    self.save()
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(concert=self)
    for ticket in tickets:
        ticket.delete()
```

or so...

If you have a large number of tickets, that may take a while, deleting them in a for loop so you may want to consider doing that in a background / asynchronous way somehow